# Change PORT for LDAP

Tags: php, ldap

I am trying to connect to LDAP. I know that default port is 389 but we have changed it to 636.

I have this part of code

```
private static $HOST = "mywebpage.com";

// Connect to LDAP
$link_id = ldap_connect(self::$HOST);
$bind_result = ldap_bind($link_id, self::$APP_DN, self::$SERVER_PASSWORD);
error_log(print_r($link_id,true)); //returns resource id #6
error_log(print_r($bind_result,true)); //returns 1

if (!$bind_result)
{
    error_log("Failed to bind to LDAP server."); 
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to bind to LDAP server.");
}
```

Is there any way to add the new port somehow? I tried

```
$link_id = ldap_connect(self::$HOST,"636");
```

But didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of [`ldap_connect()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php) with 2 parameters `$host` and `$port` is deprecated (also the port should be an integer).

The correct function signature is :

```
ldap_connect ( string|null $uri = null ) : resource|false
```

An LDAP URI should look like `ldap://hostname:port` or `ldaps://hostname:port` when using SSL encryption :

```
$link_id = ldap_connect('ldap://' . self::$HOST . ':636');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know if also ldap_bind have changed? I have this in my code.
        $bind_result = ldap_bind($link_id, self::$APP_DN, self::$SERVER_PASSWORD);

Comment: No ldap_bind() hasn't changed, if you cannot bind check the connection first, @see example https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php.